# Flutter: Animation - How to make an animated list?

Tags: listview, animation, dart, flutter

there. I'm starting to learn animation in Flutter and I don't know how to make the listview of item appear gradually like this gif:
[animation item of listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw3NN.gif)

Comment: try `SlideTransition`

Comment: Use `AnimatedList`

Answer (score 1):

As other's said, you can use `AnimatedList` in combination with `SlideTransition` to achieve the effect in the above video. You can see my answer with full demo in another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121771/9449426).